# Object oriented problem C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, oop

I have two objects. One of them has the other object.

```
User     
-----
ID
Name
Surname

UserAddress
------------
ID
UserID
Address
```

When I change the first one(User),This object in the second one(UserAddress), does not change. How can I fix it?

I am adding objects to hashtable. When I need to list my data, I use this hashtable.When I update the object, I find the index of this object in the hashtable.After that I update. But this object which is hided in the second object is not updated.

I am taking into userAddress-object user address information from database.

```
_userAddress= new userAddress();

_userAddress.ID = Convert.ToInt32(d["ID"]);

_userAddress.Address= d["Address"].ToString();

////I am taking user object here. _userAddress.UserID=           (Address)_userDa.Detail(Convert.ToInt32(d["UserID"]), conStr);
```

When I change the User object, same user object in the userAddress object does not change.

Comment: How does `UserAddress` contain a `User` instance? I see `UserID`, which assume corresponds to the ID of an existing `User`, but I don't see a property that references an instance of `User`.

Comment: Could you post your code on how you are manipulating the objects?

Comment: how are you "changing" it? I'm assuming that's a database!?

Comment: UserAddress has a UserID field - is this supposed to store a reference to the `User` or is it a representation of the user's id (such as an int or a Guid)?

Comment: Why would you expect it to? And in what way does one object "have" the other (you haven't shown any such encapsulation in your example)

Comment: And from an ease-of-understanding perspective shouldn't your `User` have an `Address` as opposed to an `Address` belonging to a `User`? I understand in the database it might be the other way (one to many support for instance), but when modeled in your classes I generally prefer that relationship to be inverted, so that from a User I can easily get a list of their addresses.   Not so important to the specifics of this question eitherway.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the 2 classes have a reference to each other, you are not likely to see the changes.  You can have something like -

```
class User
{
   UserAddress Address {get;set;}
   //Other properties
}

User u = new User();
u.Address = new UserAddress();
```

Likewise, UserAddress should have reference to the User object and not the ID alone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to apply a RDBMS behavior to objects.  If the UserID field offers no useful purpose outside the C# code, you should delete it.

In any event, add User as a property to the UserAddress class.  Remove UserId from UserAddress.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are thinking in a relational DB way.

Your User object should either have a UserAddress object as a property (or a collection of them, assuming multiple addresses are allowed - hence the need for the relationship).

Your data access implementation should then take care of the updates to the underlying tables (or whatever storage mechanism you are using)

Answer (score 0):

What type is ID?

If it's value type, it can't work.

If it's reference type, make sure you have a reference to the same ID object.

Better approach is to have references-
User->UserAddress
UserAddress->User

Then you can just do - userAddress.User.ID
or user.ID
to get the same ID.